# Не могу найти пакет yum-plugin на CentOS 8.1

Tags: linux, yum, centos8

На CentOS 8.1 не могу установить yum-plugin, основные репозитории + epel включены. Гугл ответов не дал,на моих рабочих серверах CentOS 6-7 такой проблемы не наблюдаю. Я относительно неопытный в администрировании и пока не могу понять, в каком репозитории этот пакет должен находиться. Help ? :)

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum search yum-plugin
Last metadata expiration check: 0:44:16 ago on Mon 30 Mar 2020 01:06:06 PM CEST.
No matches found.
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum repolist
Last metadata expiration check: 0:33:11 ago on Mon 30 Mar 2020 01:06:06 PM CEST.
repo id                           repo name                                                                   status
AppStream                         CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                        5,120
BaseOS                            CentOS-8 - Base                                                             2,126
PowerTools                        CentOS-8 - PowerTools                                                       1,525
*epel                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                              5,120
*epel-modular                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                          0
extras                            CentOS-8 - Extras                                                              13
```

Answer (score 0):

в итоге на английском SOF подсказали, что вместо yum'a теперь dnf начиная с 8 версии. https://www.2daygeek.com/dnf-yum-comparison/